# How does aggregate generalise fold and fold generalise reduce?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As far as I understand `aggregate` is a generalisation of `fold` which in turn is a generalisation of `reduce`.

Similarily `combineByKey` is a generalisation of `aggregateByKey` which in turn is a generalisation of `foldByKey` which in turn is a generalisation of `reduceByKey`.

However I have trouble finding simple examples for each of those seven methods which can in turn only be expressed by them and not their less general versions. For example I found http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-rdd-fold/ giving an example for `fold`, but I have been able to use `reduce` in the same situation as well.

What I found out so far:

- I read that the more generalised methods can be more efficient, but that would be a non-functional requirement and I would like to get examples which can not be implemented with the more specific method.
- I also read that e.g. the function passed to `fold` only has to be associative, while the one for `reduce` has to be commutative additionally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158790/4533188 (However, I still don't know any good simple example.) whereas in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635928/4533188 I read that fold needs both properties to hold...
- We could think of the zero value as a feature (e.g. for `fold` over `reduce`) as in "add all elements and add 3" and using 3 as the zero value, but that would be misleading, because 3 would be added for each partition, not just once. Also this is simply not the purpose of `fold` as far as I understood - it wasn't meant as a feature, but as a necessity to implement it to be able to take non-commutative functions.

What would simple examples for those seven methods be?

Answer (score 12):

Let's work through what is actually needed logically.

First, note that if your collection is unordered, *any* set of (binary) operations on it need to be both commutative and associative, or you'll get different answers depending on which (arbitrary) order you choose each time.  Since `reduce`, `fold`, and `aggregate` all use binary operations, if you use these things on a collection that is unordered (or is viewed as unordered), everything must be commutative and associative.

`reduce` is an implementation of the idea that if you can take two things and turn them into one thing, you can collapse an arbitrarily long collection into a single element.  *Associativity* is exactly the property that it doesn't matter how you pair things up as long as you eventually pair them all and keep the left-to-right order unchanged, so that's exactly what you need.

```
a   b   c   d          a   b   c   d           a   b   c   d
a # b   c   d          a # b   c   d           a   b # c   d
(a#b)   c # d          (a#b) # c   d           a   (b#c)   d
(a#b) # (c#d)          ((a#b)#c) # d           a # ((b#c)#d)
```

All of the above are the same as long as the operation (here called `#`) is associative.  There is no reason to swap around which things go on the left and which go on the right, so the operation does *not* need to be commutative (addition is: a+b == b+a; concat is not: ab != ba).

**`reduce` is mathematically simple and requires only an associative operation**

Reduce is limited, though, in that it doesn't work on empty collections, and in that you can't change the type.  If you're working sequentially, you can a function that takes a new type and the old type, and produces something with the new type.  This is a **sequential fold** (left-fold if the new type goes on the left, right-fold if it goes on the right).  There is *no choice* about the order of operations here, so commutativity and associativity and everything are irrelevant.  There's exactly one way to work through your list sequentially.  (If you want your left-fold and right-fold to always be the same, then the operation must be associative and commutative, but since left- and right-folds don't generally get accidentally swapped, this isn't very important to ensure.)

The problem comes when you want to work in parallel.  You can't sequentially go through your collection; that's not parallel by definition!  So you have to insert the new type at *multiple* places!  Let's call our fold operation `@`, and we'll say that the new type goes on the left.  Furthermore, we'll say that we always start with the same element, `Z`.  Now we could do any of the following (and more):

```
  a     b     c     d        a     b     c     d         a     b     c     d
 Z@a    b     c     d       Z@a    b    Z@c    d        Z@a   Z@b   Z@c   Z@d
(Z@a) @ b     c     d      (Z@a) @ b   (Z@c) @ d
((Z@a)@b)  @  c     d
(((Z@a)@b)@c)    @  d
```

Now we have a collection of one or more things of the new type.  (If the original collection was empty, we just take `Z`.)  We know what to do with that!  Reduce!  So we make a reduce operation for our new type (let's call it `$`, and remember it has to be associative), and then we have **aggregate**:

```
  a     b     c     d        a     b     c     d         a     b     c     d
 Z@a    b     c     d       Z@a    b    Z@c    d        Z@a   Z@b   Z@c   Z@d
(Z@a) @ b     c     d      (Z@a) @ b   (Z@c) @ d        Z@a $ Z@b   Z@c $ Z@d
((Z@a)@b)  @  c     d      ((Z@a)@b) $ ((Z@c)@d)    ((Z@a)$(Z@b)) $ ((Z@c)$(Z@d))
(((Z@a)@b)@c)    @  d
```

Now, these things all look really different.  How can we make sure that they end up to be the same?  There is no single concept that describes this, but the `Z@` operation has to be *zero-like* and `$` and `@` have to be homomorphic, in that we need `(Z@a)@b == (Z@a)$(Z@b)`.  That's the *actual* relationship that you need (and it is technically very similar to a semigroup homomorphism).  There are all sorts of ways to pick badly even if everything is associative and commutative.  For example, if `Z` is the double value `0.0` and `@` is actually `+`, then `Z` is zero-like and `@` is associative and commutative.  But if `$` is actually `*`, which is *also* associative and commutative, everything goes wrong:

```
(0.0+2) * (0.0+3) == 2.0 * 3.0 == 6.0
((0.0+2) + 3)     == 2.0 + 3   == 5.0
```

One example of a non-trival aggregate is building a collection, where `@` is the "append an element" operator and `$` is the "concat two collections" operation.

**`aggregate` is tricky and requires an associative reduce operation, plus a zero-like value and a fold-like operation that is homomorphic to the reduce**

The bottom line is that `aggregate` is not *simply* a generalization of `reduce`.

But there is a simplification (less general form) if you're not actually changing the type.  If `Z` is actually `z` and is an actual zero, we can just stick it in wherever we want and use reduce.  Again, we *don't need commutativity* conceptually; we just stick in one or more `z`'s and reduce, and our `@` and `$` operations can be the same thing, namely the original `#` we used on the reduce

```
  a   b   c   d             () <- empty
 z#a z#b                    z
 z#a (z#b)#c
 z#a ((z#b)#c)#d
(z#a)#((z#b)#c)#d
```

If we just delete the `z`'s from here, it works perfectly well, and in fact is equivalent to `if (empty) z else reduce`.  But there's another way it could work too.  If the operation `#` is also *commutative*, *and* `z` is not actually a zero but just occupies a fixed point of `#` (meaning `z#z == z` but `z#a` is not necessarily just `a`), then you can run the same thing, and since commutivity lets you switch the order around, you conceptually can reorder all the z's together at the beginning, and then merge them all together.

And this is a *parallel fold*, which is really a rather different beast than a sequential fold.

(Note that neither `fold` nor `aggregate` are strictly generalizations of `reduce` even for unordered collections where operations have to be associative and commutative, as some operations do not have a sensible zero!  For instance, reducing strings by shortest length has as its "zero" the longest possible string, which conceptually doesn't exist, and practically is an absurd waste of memory.)

**`fold` requires an associative reduce operation plus *either* a zero value *or* a reduce operation that's commutative plus a fixed-point value**

Now, when would you *ever* use a parallel fold that *wasn't* just a reduceOrElse(zero)?  Probably never, actually, though they can exist.  For example, if you have a ring, you often have fixed points of the type we need.  For instance, 10 % 45 == (10*10) % 45, and `*` is both associative and commutative in integers mod 45.  Thus, if our collection is numbers mod 45, we can fold with a "zero" of `10` and an operation of `*`, and parallelize however we please while still getting the same result.  Pretty weird.

However, note that you *can* just plug the zero and operation of `fold` into `aggregate` and get exactly the same result, so `aggregate` *is* a proper generalization of `fold`.

So, bottom line:

1. Reduce requires only an associative merge operation, but doesn't change the type, and doesn't work on empty collecitons.
2. Parallel fold tries to extend `reduce` but requires a true zero, or a fixed point and the merge operation must be commutative.
3. Aggregate changes the type by (conceptually) running sequential folds followed by a (parallel) reduce, but there are complex relationships between the reduce operation and the fold operation--basically they have to be doing "the same thing".
4. An unordered collection (e.g. a set) always requires an associative and commutative operation for any of the above.

With regard to the `byKey` stuff: it's just the same as this, except it only applies it to the collection of values associated with a (potentially repeated) key.

If Spark actually requires commutativity where the above analysis does not suggest it's needed, one could reasonably consider that a bug (or at least an unnecessary limitation of the implementation, given that operations like `map` and `filter` preserve order on ordered RDDs).

Comment: The subtle problem here is the assumption that the collection is ordered and order of operations is specified and deterministic and in general case neither of these is true for `RDDs`. It is pretty much the same issue as with Scala parallel collections where `reduce` require _associative binary operator_ but the _the order in which operations are performed on elements is unspecified and may be nondeterministic_.

Comment: At the same time for sequential operations on parallel collections, like `reduceRight`, one may get _different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered. or the operator is associative and commutative_.

Comment: @zero323 - Thanks for the point about unordered collections (I added that to my answer).  However, I maintain that requiring more than an _associative_ operator for reduce on a collection that is intrinsically ordered is an unnecessary implementation restriction.  Parallel operations on Scala collections do _not_ switch left-to-right order on a fold or reduce, so you can successfully use associative-but-not-commutative operations like string concat in them.

Answer (score 1):

> the function passed to fold only has to be associative, while the one for reduce has to be commutative additionally.

It is not correct. `fold` on RDDs requires the function to be commutative as well. It is not the same operation as `fold` on [`Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable) what is pretty well described in [the official documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0f1f31d3a6669fbac474518cf2a871485e202bdc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1016):

> This behaves somewhat differently from fold operations implemented for non-distributed
>      collections in functional languages like Scala.
>
> This `fold` operation may be applied to
>      partitions individually, and then fold those results into the final result, rather than
>      apply the `fold` to each element sequentially in some defined ordering. For functions
>      that are not commutative, the result may differ from that of a fold applied to a
>      non-distributed collection.

As you can see order of merging partial values is not part of the contract hence function which is used for `fold` has to be commutative.

> I read that the more generalised methods can be more efficient

Technically speaking there should be no significant difference. For `fold` vs `reduce` you can check my answers to [reduce() vs. fold() in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36056895/1560062) and [Why is the fold action necessary in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34529953/1560062)

Regarding `*byKey` methods all are implemented using the same basic construct which is  `combineByKeyWithClassTag` and can be reduced to three simple operations:

- `createCombiner` - create "zero" value for a given partition
- `mergeValue` - merge values into accumulator
- `mergeCombiners` - merge accumulators created for each partition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25158790/4533188 said that being commutative is not required...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: ??? I said commutativity is not required, but associativity. You quote the same and say the opposite? What do you mean?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, Make42 - docs actually clearly explain that `RDD.fold` is not the same as local `fold`.

Comment: Do all of the seven methods need to get function that are associative and commutative?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by _seven methods_ but you can safely assume that this is indeed the case. You can also check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35205107/1560062 It is possible to aggregate data with commutative-only function by explicitly merging results on the driver but it is completely different approach and provided by built-in aggregation methods.

Comment: The once I mentioned: `reduce`, `fold`, `aggregate`, `reduceByKey`, `foldByKey`, `aggregateByKey`, `combineByKey`.

Comment: Yes, they all require function to be both associative and commutative.